# How to hide column in odoo 12?

Tags: odoo-12

Please i need to hide column "Description" in table "Order Lines" in form view external_id="sale.view_order_form", hide this column if details==True

Here is python code:

```
class ClassSaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    details = fields.Boolean()
```

Here is xml file :

```
<record id="module_sale_order_line_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">module.sale.order.line.form</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
            <field name="details"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: add attribute in your field which you want to hide attrs={'invisible':[('default','=',True)]}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`position='attributes'`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#inheritance-specs) and define the value for `invisible` attribute.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/form/group/field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">[('details', '=', True)]</attribute>                
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for making description field invisible when details is true

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible':[('details', '=', True)]}</attribute>                
</xpath>
```